# Zend Application from Sub directory getting Zend layout links working correctly

Tags: php, zend-framework, .htaccess

I have setup a Zend application in a sub directory.  Dont ask why I just had to do it that way (not my preferred method) but I don't have that choice. The Zend application resides in a subdirectory called dsa.

```
http://dsa.dev/dsa
```

My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php [QSA,L]
```

This works and will bootstrap the application.  I can go to my root directories and other directories for other things without any problems.

In my application.ini I have set

```
resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/dsa".
```

In my layout.phtml file if I var_dump the path it looks like this.

```
var_dump($this->baseUrl('css/main.css'));
http://dsa.dev/dsa/css/main.css
```

None of the links work, all css and js files are not linking correctly.  If you hit F12 and look at them you get a 404 not found for any file.  What do I need to do to get the correct paths to show the files.  This is the first time I have tried setting zend up in a sub directory and obviously I'm not doing something right.  I have read everything I can find on this subject.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least one problem I see is that the rewrite rules in the `.htaccess` file are incorrect.

Given these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php [QSA,L]
```

Those rules equate to:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]` # The request is a regular file with size > 0
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]` # The request is to a file that is a symlink
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]` # The request is to a directory that exists

And if any of the above are true, the request is rewritten to `public/index.php` which is not correct.  If the request is for a file that exists on disk, you DO NOT want to rewrite it; instead you just want to serve that file.

The correct `.htaccess` file should look something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ public/index.php [NC,L]
```

This says, if the request is for a file with size > 0, a directory, or a symlink, then route the request to the actual file requested (`RewriteRule ^.*$ -`).  If none of those conditions are true, then rewrite the request to index.php.

On a separate note, I would go ahead and get rid of the `public` directory altogether.  Take the contents of `public` and put them in `/dsa`.  `dsa` is now your `public` folder.  You can store your `application` directory anywhere on the system, or if you have to place it in the `dsa` folder due to filesystem restrictions, make sure to add a rule to your `.htaccess` file that denies all access to the `application` folder.  Then you just need to make a quick change to your `index.php` file telling it the correct path to `application` using the `APPLICATION_PATH` constant.

I believe those two changes should fix your problems.

Comment: Would it be wrong to create a fake account so I could upvote this twice? Great answer!

Comment: @Phil Maybe, but no objections from me ;) jk.  Thanks for the comment/

Comment: Thanks for this post it was really good and straight to the point.  I'm going through and working out your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a `RewriteBase /dsa` in your .htaccess.

Comment: Already tried all of that but didn't see any difference in the way it was being handled.