# How to remove "public" from url using routeing in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, routes

An one issue in my zend, i write rule in .htaccess to remove "public" from url as following,

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-name.com/$ [OR]<br/>
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/<br/>
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]<br/>
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but there is ROUTE method in zend, i have use it for multiple language to set language code in url LIKE **www.domain-name.com/en/** , using **zend_controller_router_route_chain**,

before this method implemented, my url is **www.domain-name.com** but
when i use this method in my zend project, may be it overwrites .htaccess rule of removing "public" from URL or something happen using same and "public" is displaying in url like **www.domain-name.com/public**.

so IS THERE ANY METHOD OR TRICK TO REMOVE PUBLIC FROM URL USING ANY METHOD OF **ROUTE** IN ZEND FRAMEWORK ???

Thanks,

**MRJethva**.

Answer (score 10):

The following works for me using ZF2.2

Create index.php on ZF2 root directory and add the following content:

```
<?php 
define('RUNNING_FROM_ROOT', true);
include 'public/index.php';
```

Create .htaccess on ZF2 root directory and add the following content:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Finally, add this conditional statement in the top of your layout.phtml file:

```
<?php 
if (defined('RUNNING_FROM_ROOT')) {
  $this->plugin('basePath')->setBasePath($this->basePath().'/public');
} ?>
```

Enjoy!

Reference: http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/zend-framework-on-a-shared-host/

Comment: its working fine, but now its unable to get the images from image folder. Can you please help me out in this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and you don't need `Zend_Route`.  Delete the `public` folder and put the Zend Framework files from it (`index.php`, `.htaccess`, etc) in your root directory (e.g. `htdocs`).  You can place the `application` folder and other Zend Framework files outside of your web root where they cannot be accessed over HTTP.

All you need to do is edit `index.php` and change the `APPLICATION_PATH` to the correct path.  This way your Zend Application will run from your root directory and you won't need to use `mod_rewrite` to hide the public folder.

See the last part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809822/zend-application-from-sub-directory-getting-zend-layout-links-working-correctly/9814080#9814080) for a similar example.

Comment: there is no APPLICATION_PATH  constant how do i find it??

Answer (score 0):

zf2 and zf3  remove **Public** from URL

create index.php and .htaccess add file in root of project

add the line in index.php
**include_once("public/index.php");**

and in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

after that go to following path

Module->application(module name)->view->layout->layout.phtml
change css and js path add public in path

before

->prependStylesheet($this->basePath('css/bootstrap.min.css'))

->prependFile($this->basePath('js/bootstrap.min.js'))

after

->prependStylesheet($this->basePath('public/css/bootstrap.min.css'))

->prependFile($this->basePath('public/js/bootstrap.min.js'))

also in image path