# PHP Zend - Hide public in URL

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm using PHP Zend as my project framework. How I can remove `public` from this URL?

I want this kind of URL

```
http://staging.revivalx.com/zeesbio/login
```

Instead of this

```
http://staging.revivalx.com/zeesbio/public/login
```

http://staging.revivalx.com/zeesbio/public/login

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove "public" from url using routeing in zend framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834328/how-to-remove-public-from-url-using-routeing-in-zend-framework)

Comment: Than try with a htaccess rule as mention [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19708714/htaccess-remove-public-from-url).

Comment: Zf1 or Zf2? Both have a routing system you can use to match the url to a controller/action.

Comment: I'm using the old one, ZF1.

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834328/how-to-remove-public-from-url-using-routeing-in-zend-framework

Answer (score 0):

Try to put .htaccess file in your root directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =''
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

php_value memory_limit 64M

#add content type header 
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```