# how to remove public and index.php from ZF2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, zend-framework2

I want to remove public folder and index.php from my url.

Example
My current url looks like

```
http://localhost/elibrary/public/
```

i want to remove public, and my url should looks like

```
http://localhost/elibrary/
```

my .htaccess file contains.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /elibrary/

## Adding a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?[^/])[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [L,R=301]

# remove /public/ from URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ public/$1 [L]
```

i read this article [.htaccess: remove public from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19708714/htaccess-remove-public-from-url) and comes up with above .htaccess file. this .htaccess file remove public folder successfully but all web formating like css is lost.
But when i tried this `http://localhost/elibrary/index.php/` it shows 404 page but all formating come back.

How can i successfully remove public and index.php from my url ? i am using zend framework 2

Comment: I changed .haccess file as per above suggestion. but it shows me file and directory listing in browser. and If I click on public folder it opens website. Why the above solution is not working for me.

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834328/how-to-remove-public-from-url-using-routeing-in-zend-framework

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would stick with the standard .htaccess file, ie;

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

And make changes in your httpd.con /apache2.conf - depending on what server you have, to include the "public" in both DocumentRoot and Directory

eg;

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/elibrary/public/"

<Directory "/var/www/html/elibrary/public">
```

This way you wont break any other coding / paths

Answer (score 0):

Change your last rule to this:

```
# remove /public/ from URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ public/$1 [L]
```

And make sure to use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.