# Redirect request to public directory zend

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, web-deployment

I have a sub domain to which i have deployed my zend application, the problem is it points to the directory say `abc` and i cannot get it changed to point it to `public` directory is there a way i can put a `.htaccess` file on the root which will redirect to the `public` directory? can it be done? is there another way i can get it done

my index.php inside public dir

```
<?php

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';



// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

my `.htaccess` inside public dir

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

currently the directory structure looks like

```
/myroot
 -.settings
 -application
 -docs
 -library
 -public
 -tests
 -.buildpath
 -.proect
 -.zfproject.xml
```

Comment: @AlexHowansky can you please provide some guidance how can i create one so to create an illusion that server is pointing to `mysubdomain/public` currently its pointing to the root of sub domain

Comment: If your web server config has /path/to/abc set as document root and you can't change that, then just remove (or rename) /path/to/abc (if it exists) and do: `ln -s /path/to/mysubdomain/public /path/to/abc` This will make /path/to/abc appear to exist to the web server, but it's just a pointer to your app which is elsewhere.

Comment: Just get rid of the public folder altogether.  Copy all of its contents and move them to the directory `abc`.  Just adjust index.php if necessary to correctly define your `APPLICATION_PATH`.

Comment: @drew010 can you tell me what changes i should make i'll post the index.php, does the .htaccess needed to be changed too

Comment: @john No changes are required to the `.htaccess` file.  You may not need to change the `APPLICATION_PATH` either but it depends on where you are storing the Zend App files.  The line in question is `define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));`  Just adjust the second part of that define so that the path to `application` is correct.  It could be in the `abc` directory, or you could store it outside of the web root in which case it might be `../../application` instead of just `../application`.

Comment: i am hosting zend application files inside the library directory

Comment: @drew010 please see the question edit i have update it with the root directory structure

Comment: @john Is `myroot` just `/home/username/public_html/abc` ?  For the sake of keeping your directory less cluttered, I would try to move all the application files (everything except contents of public) somewhere else, i.e. `/home/username/abcapp` and putting index.php and .htaccess in `/home/username/public_html/abc`

Comment: Here is a similar answer to your question, the last paragraph is relevant to you.  You are trying to do the same thing ultimately.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809822/zend-application-from-sub-directory-getting-zend-layout-links-working-correctly/9814080#9814080

Comment: FYI: If this is hosted on GoDaddy like I recall from another question you shouldn't have a problem to set a sub domain to a folder. There is a little problem with their GUI version, though. You have to manually set the path. I've moved away from GoDaddy but didn't have a prob to set it up there.

Comment: @AdrianWorld you are right when i hosted the application on godaddy only the home page is showing up but when i try to navigate to another link it gives me a internal server error please have a look http://psnm.stuffmeta.com

Comment: @AdrianWorld this i am trying on another hosting server where i just have the access to the sub domain's root in side that i have my application files and directories like public, application etc

Comment: ok, then you should be able to set the RedirectRule to `public/index.php` but you'll also have add the [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) to `/public`

Comment: so you are saying i put this line `RewriteBase /public` in the `.htaccess` inside the public dir? sorry if i sound like an idiot its been 10 hours im struggling to deploy the site and messed up at the moment

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

no errors and no problems..

Comment: This is the best answer. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I hope I get your domain setup correctly. If you have this setup

```
sub.domain.net --> /myroot
```

you will need an .htaccess in that (/myroot) folder because it is the base of your http requests. It should look like this

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /public  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d  
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]  
RewriteRule ^.*$ public/index.php [NC,L]
```

The RewriteBase directive should find all request in the RewriteCond and applies mainly to the first RewriteRule. It basically sets (rewrites) the relative root for all HTTP path request. The second RewriteRule finally triggers your application which is a local path. (I hope I am not wrong about this last rule. If that doesn't work try without the public. I can't test it but I had got an app to work like this a few years back.)

Comment: the error still remains it says internal server error you can see it here http://psnm.stuffmeta.com  its the same error that i was getting before putting the .htaccess at my root, i just couldn't understand why the home page is shown its in the index controller but when i try to access another action of the same index controller i get the error

Comment: The home page works because your index.php is found for it. All other requests are looking for the path and because the path doesn't exist an error occurs. The .htaccess in /myroot with the RewriteBase should fix that, though.

Comment: I found the old config and it somehow worked like that. I've tried to replicate the situation but I'm struggling with other issues. Somehow the simplest of rules won't work. I will call it day now.

Comment: ok, just a clarification at my godaddy account i have made the public directory web server root

Comment: I had the same issue and applied your feedback. It works without "public/" in the last RewriteRule as you mentioned. Thank you for sharing your knowledge.